# Want to retrieve Array from database

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq, highcharts

I'm pretty new to MVC and have some problem with Linq, I think the solution would be pretty simple.

I have a table in a database with the following variables;

Name - string

Value - float

Time- Datetime

Now i want to make a specific name into two arrays, one containing the Values and the other one the Time so it will be easy to plot. I have made a controller where i have manage to access the database and get the specific name out with this code;

```
        var Names = db.Graphs
                        .Where(r => r.Name.Contains(Name) ||
                                    string.IsNullOrEmpty(Name))
                        .Take(10)
```

But im completely stuck on how to itterate through the database, get two arrays and send it to the View where i have my Highchart-plot.

Javascript;

```
  series: [{
            name: 'NameOn',
            data: [23.3, 18.3, 13.9, 9.6]   <--- Where i want to insert my data
        }]
```

Any idea on how to retrieve the data?

Comment: This suggestion is not about your question but, you can use [dotNetHighcharts](http://dotnethighcharts.codeplex.com)

Comment: It seems to be a nice implementation, but i still have to retrive the value from the database.

Comment: If you want to use DotnetHighCharts I will give you an example data format. (Name, value, date)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For irregularTimeChart data format is like following

```
public static Series GetIrregularTimeChartData()
{
    List<Series> Series = new List<Series>();

    // get data from db and convert it to chart data (name, value, date)
    var chartSeries = db.Graphs.GroupBy(x => new { x.Name })
                      .Select(g => new
                      {
                          Name = g.Key,
                          Data = g.Select(x => x.Value).ToArray(),
                          Date = g.Select(x => x.Date).ToArray()
                      }).ToArray();

    // create 2D array => [value, date]
    foreach (var item in chartSeries)
    {
        int lenght = item.Data.Count();
        object[,] data = new object[lenght, 2];
        for (int i = 0; i < lenght; i++)
        {
            data[i, 0] = item.Date[i];
            data[i, 1] = item.Data[i];
        }
        Series localSeries = new Series { Name = item.Name, Data = new Data(data) };
        Series.Add(localSeries);
    }

    return Series;
}
```

set this data to chart data source. You can use [examples in this page](http://dotnethighcharts.codeplex.com/releases/view/85324) for more info.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! :) i get;LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'Int32[] ToArray[Int32](System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[System.Int32])' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression.  on the try to get chartseries.

Comment: First get `var list = db.Graphs.ToList()` and after getting list, then group it. `var groupped = list.group...`

Comment: I solved it with this code:                              .Select(x => x.Temp).OrderBy(x => x).ToArray();
many thanks for the Help AliRiza